# Извлечение контента из pdb (program debug database, вроде так)

Tags: отладка, visual-c++, c++, reverse-engineering

Добрый день, господа.

У меня есть файлы data.pdb и data_pc.pdb, там хранятся картинки и аудио, как их оттуда вытащить и сохранить в отдельные файлы?

так вот выглядит все внутри файла:
[image]

Comment: Как Вы их туда засунули, так и доставайте. Откуда они у Вас там? Чем-то мне это напоминает анекдот о советской хирургии -- удаление гланд через задний проход.

Comment: Сувал их туда не я, и не знаю, как их туда запихали, поэтому и спрашиваю. Это файловый пак из одной игры, что дали, с тем и работаю.

Comment: для меня pdb - это то, что генерирует VisualStudia в помощь при отладке (отладочные символы). Для большинства майкрософтовских dll их можно утащить с сайта МС.

Если же это какая то малоизвестная игра, то причем здесь отладка?

Если это реально отладочные символы, то используйте саму студию или любой нормальный отладчик/дизассемблер (например IDA) и отлаживайте. Но вот только картинок и видео в нем не будет.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что pdb в данном случае, вовсе не файл с отладочной информацией, а просто так встали звезды.

Comment: Как это нету там файлов? Игра пишет в лог, что лоадит эти файлы, а потом получает спрайты, по такой логике - не понять откуда о_О. В директории игры только пдб и длл, больше ничего нет...

Comment: Да, иногда посмотрев на кусок файла, можно угадать содержимое. Но не всегда. Очень часто содержимое можно угадать, если знать дополнительную информацию, например сколько картинок/музыки и в каком формате должно быть, какие размеры, нет ли у них названий (часто при загрузке они отображаются), может кто то уже ковырял эту игру. Но Вы боитесь даже название сообщить.

Comment: @Arc тогда получается, что здесь PDB вовсе не Program DataBase (отладочная информация), а какой-то свой внутренний формат игры. В теории чтоб его разобрать нужно сделать следующее: или найти редактор ресурсов игры, или самостоятельно дизассемблировать код игры и понять как там внутри все устроено. Как вариант, возможно, что кто-то часть работы сделал.

Comment: Пдб полностью распознается в студии, так что нет. Прекрасно осознаю глупость вопроса, но уже не знаю, что думать, в длл файлы могут быть?\

Comment: Да, кстати, может кто ковырял, или не поленится поковырять, вот ссыль на установщик Лайт версии, называется "Archibald's adventures"  http://www.gameofyear.com/download/archibald_install.exe

Comment: @Arc в dll (и exe, что почти одно и тоже), могут быть ресурсы. А что там -- хз. Т.е. меню/иконки/картинки/строки/фонты -- это предопределённые типы, но возможны и application-defined resource (raw data) -- тип RT_RCDATA. Не исключено, что игрописцы использовали их...

Comment: @alexlz , что это за такое? Внутри длл находится? Означает ли это, что при преобразовании длл обратно в норм формат, я получу файлы?

Comment: @Arc тут лучше специалистов по виндам спросить. Вот статья из педивикии, там ссылки на софт для манипулирования ресурсами. Посмотрите, может поможет. А может нет. Это только версия.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29

Comment: Завтра поставлю софт типа "dlltocpp", и попробую что-нибудь поискать-получить, после чего отпишусь

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось достаточно связаться с создателями игры и от них получить искомые спрайты игры.